# WPF how do I create a textbox dynamically and find the textbox on a button click?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox, mouseevent

I am creating a `TextBox` and a `Button` dynamically using the following code:

```
Button btnClickMe = new Button();
btnClickMe.Content = "Click Me";
btnClickMe.Name = "btnClickMe";
btnClickMe.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.CallMeClick);

someStackPanel.Childern.Add(btnClickMe);

TextBox txtNumber = new TextBox();
txtNumber.Name = "txtNumber";
txtNumber.Text = "1776";

someStackPanel.Childern.Add(txtNumber);
```

I hook up to a click event to the `Click Me` button.  The click me button even is fired correctly.  However I cannot find the `TextBox` I entered dynamically.

Here is my click me event:

```
protected void ClickMeClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Find the phone number
    TextBox txtNumber = this.someStackPanel.FindName("txtNumber") as TextBox;

    if (txtNumber != null)
    {
        string message = string.Format("The number is {0}", txtNumber.Text);

        MessageBox.Show(message);    
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Textbox is null");
    }
}
```

How can I find the `TextBox` `txtNumber`?

Comment: did you mean this.someStackPanel.FindName("txtNumber")  ?

Comment: Thanks I fixed it.  It still doesn't work.

Comment: Lots of typos in this:
(1) s/Childern/Children/
(2) Button is routed to CallMeClick but code shows ClickMeClick
(3) Button is placed into someStackPanel but is later searched for in pnlCallMe
Evidently, this is not the code you are running.

Comment: No this is not the code I am running.  I took the code I was running and changed it and made it more general, and showed only the pieces that were needed for my question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Josh G had the clue that fixed this code: use RegisterName().

Three benefits here:

1. Doesn't use a member variable to save the reference to the dynamically created TextBox.
2. Compiles.
3. Complete code.

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Windows;
   using System.Windows.Controls;

   namespace AddControlsDynamically
   {
       public partial class Window1 : Window
       {
           public void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
               GenerateControls();
           }
           public void GenerateControls()
           {
               Button btnClickMe = new Button();
               btnClickMe.Content = "Click Me";
               btnClickMe.Name = "btnClickMe";
               btnClickMe.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.CallMeClick);
               someStackPanel.Children.Add(btnClickMe);
               TextBox txtNumber = new TextBox();
               txtNumber.Name = "txtNumber";
               txtNumber.Text = "1776";
               someStackPanel.Children.Add(txtNumber);
               someStackPanel.RegisterName(txtNumber.Name, txtNumber);
           }
           protected void CallMeClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
               TextBox txtNumber = (TextBox) this.someStackPanel.FindName("txtNumber");
               string message = string.Format("The number is {0}", txtNumber.Text);
               MessageBox.Show(message);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This works out quite well.  I changing this to the accepted answer because it does what I originally wanted. The other works well too, but I did not want to create textbox and store them.

Answer (score 7):

Another method is to set the associated `TextBox` as `Button Tag` when instanciating them.

```
btnClickMe.Tag = txtNumber;
```

This way you can retrieve it back in event handler.

```
protected void ClickMeClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btnClickMe = sender as Button;
    if (btnClickMe != null)
    {
        TextBox txtNumber = btnClickMe.Tag as TextBox;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get your original click handler to work by registering the name of the text box:

```
someStackPanel.RegisterName(txtNumber.Name, txtNumber);
```

This will then allow you to call FindName on the StackPanel and find the TextBox.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do a comprehensive search through the visual tree of controls, you can use the VisualTreeHelper class.

Use the following code to iterate through all of the visual children of a control:

```
for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentObj); i++)
{
    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

    if (child is TextBox)
        // Do something
}
```

If you want to search down into the tree, you will want to perform this loop recursively, like so:

```
public delegate void TextBoxOperation(TextBox box);

public bool SearchChildren(DependencyObject parent, TextBoxOperation op)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

        TextBox box = child as TextBox;

        if (box != null)
        {
            op.Invoke(box);
            return true;
        }

        bool found = SearchChildren(child, op);

        if (found)
            return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there any way you can make the TextBox control a field in your class instead of a variable inside your generator method

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{
    private TextBox txtNumber;

    public void Window_Loaded()
    {
        GenerateControls();
    }

    public void GenerateControls()
    {
        Button btnClickMe = new Button();
        btnClickMe.Content = "Click Me";
        btnClickMe.Name = "btnClickMe";
        btnClickMe.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.CallMeClick);
        someStackPanel.Childern.Add(btnClickMe);
        txtNumber = new TextBox();
        txtNumber.Name = "txtNumber";
        txtNumber.Text = "1776";
        someStackPanel.Childern.Add(txtNumber);
    }

    protected void ClickMeClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {    
        // Find the phone number    
        string message = string.Format("The number is {0}", txtNumber.Text);        
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work.  However is there no way to find it?  What happens if I have say 10 textboxes?  Is the solution to create a List<Textbox> and just use Linq to find them?

Comment: I accepted this answer because it does work, and if I have 10 textboxes I can create a list and find them in a list.

Thanks.

Comment: The code does not compile: Childern, CallMeClick not defined, etc.

Comment: someStackPanel would have to be setup in your Xaml.  This code is based on the sample provide in the OPs question.

Comment: The List<Textbox> should work fine, your still just keeping a local reference to the control.