# How to dynamically open a Textbox on a Button click

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to open a Text box on this button click (create it in runtime, when user clicks the button), and store a string.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox dynamicTextBox = new TextBox();
    dynamicTextBox.Text = "Type Partnumber";
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you meant by "pop up a Text box". Do you want to create one in runtime and display it to the user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF how do I create a textbox dynamically and find the textbox on a button click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537073/wpf-how-do-i-create-a-textbox-dynamically-and-find-the-textbox-on-a-button-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your TextBox to Grid children and set column and row numbers.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox dynamicTextBox = new TextBox();
            dynamicTextBox.Text = "Type Partnumber";
            Grid.SetRow(dynamicTextBox, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(dynamicTextBox, 0);
            this.MainGrid.Children.Add(dynamicTextBox);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox dynamicTextBox = new TextBox();
            // your code
            this.Controls.Add(dynamicTextBox);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Say, you have a `Grid` in your `XAML` part and name it as "grid" and access that grid to add this newly created `TextBox`

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  TextBox dynamicTextBox = new TextBox();
  dynamicTextBox.Text = "Type Partnumber";
  grid.Children.Add(dynamicTextBox);
}
```